# String comparison in python

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I've been working my way through Python, but can't seem to get past string comparisons. I wrote a function that takes user input and evaluates it. User input can only be either "a" or "b", otherwise an error occurs. I have been using this:

```
def checkResponse(resp):
    #Make the incoming string trimmed & lowercase
    respRaw = resp.strip()
    respStr = respRaw.lower()
    #Make sure only a or b were chosen
    if respStr != "a" | respStr != "b":
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

However, when I input `a` or `b`, I receive this: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'`

Is this the incorrect way to compare a string? Is there a built in function to do this like with Java? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the `if` that corresponds to your `elif`?

Comment: I cut it out to reduce some unnecessary code, but I'll fix...thanks!

Comment: In addition to the points about operators in the answers below, you can chain string methods, so `return resp.strip().lower() in ('a', 'b')` can be the entire function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` is the bitwise or operator.  You want `or`.  (You actually want `and`.)

You wrote:

```
if respStr != "a" | respStr != "b":
```

Bitwise operators have high precedence (similar to other arithmetic operators), so this is equivalent to:

```
if respStr != ("a" | respStr) != "b":
```

where the two `!=` operations are [chained comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in) (`x != y != z` is equivalent to `x != y and y != z`).  It's meaningless to apply bitwise or to two strings.

You meant to write:

```
if respStr != "a" and respStr != "b":
```

You could also write, using chained operators:

```
if "a" != respStr != "b":
```

Or, using the containment operator `in`:

```
if respStr not in ("a", "b"):
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want is `respStr != 'a' and respStr != 'b'` (`or` is the boolean operator, `|` the bitwise one - however, you need `and` for your check).

However you can write the condition in an even nicer way without repeating the variable name:

```
return respStr in ('a', 'b')
```

This will return `True` if respStr is `a` or `b` and `False` otherwise.